# IsMatch() returning false for a regex in .NET

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using .Net regex tester but in my C# application, `IsMatch()` is returning false.

Here is my code :

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[0 - 9]{ 3}_RE_[0 - 9]{ 4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}_[0 - 9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}.TXT$");

string fileName = "102_RE_20120102_091013.TXT"

if (reg.IsMatch(fileName))
{
    // Control flow never reaches this block
}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `https://regex101.com/` helps you in realtime error catching! Not a real answer but I wanted to share it here.

Comment: Once you remove the spaces, it will work - https://regex101.com/r/LRKfMO/1

Answer (score 4):

Because of the unnecessary space characters inside. Try

```
^[0-9]{3}_RE_[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}.TXT$
```

Sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ggSJV

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you could also write:

`"^\d{3}_RE_\d{8}_\d{6}.TXT$"`

`\d` stands for [0-9] (digit)

If you also want to get all the date and time parts you can use 
`"^(\d{3})_RE_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).TXT$"`

Answer (score 0):

[0 - 9] : match a single caracter present in the set

[0-9] : match a single caracter in the range between 0 and 9 (case sensitive)

so use

```
^[0-9]{3}_RE_[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}.TXT$
```

You can use this online https://regex101.com/ regex tester